# How can I edit the string contents of a rich text item in the clipboard in C#?

Tags: c#, clipboard, richtext

I am working on automating a process within my business, part of which is sending an email through SalesForce. We don't have access to the SF API and the email has to be sent through salesforce in order to keep the communication searchable for the coworkers.

I need to use a template which can be selected in SalesForce, however this function does not work in IE (which our RPA solution uses) so I need to build this email from scratch.

I see two options for this:

1. Use the HTML to recreate the format with the right variables. This entails inserting/injecting/manipulating HTML.
2. Copy the format into memory/the clipboard, edit it programatically and paste it into the SF interface

This question will be about option 2. I have posted an additional question with regards to the first option separately. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096570/how-can-i-edit-html-inside-an-iframe-using-javascript).

Now on to the question: I found that I can copy the text in the template from the SalesForce webpage to the clipboard (using CTRL+C) and then paste it into word, doing so will preserve the formatting and layout of the text as well as included images. I can then copy and paste this back from word to the SF webpage as well preserving the images, format and layout. This means that the formatting and image data is retained in the clipboard.

Now I need to edit the template text before I paste it into the webpage in order to use this as a solution for automation. I have been experimenting with this for the past week but I can't find a way to edit the text while preserving the formatting and layout.

I use C# and know how to GetText and SetText as wel as images (separately) from the clipboard. However the text is then a plain string without any layout and formatting. I want to replace certain keywords in the template with the required variables.

At this point I have the following code to investigate the contents of the clipboard:

```
// Initialise a DataObject
DataObject t = null;

try
{
    // Get Data from clipboard
    t = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject(); // GetData(DataFormats.Html);

    // Get formats in the DataObject
    string[] tFormats = t.GetFormats();
    
    // For each format that was found create a separate object (I did this manually, I 
    // inspected the formats earlier by eye. 
    object objectDescriptor = t.GetData("Object Descriptor", true);
    object rtf = t.GetData("Rich Text Format", true);
    object HTMLFormat = t.GetData("HTML Format", true);
    object sysString = t.GetData("System.String", true);
    object unicodeText = t.GetData("UnicodeText", true);
    object text = t.GetData("Text", true);
    object enhancedMetafile = t.GetData("EnhancedMetafile", true);
    object metaFilePict = t.GetData("MetaFilePict", true);
    object embedSource = t.GetData("Embed Source", true);
    object linkSource = t.GetData("Link Source", true);
    object linkSourceDescriptor = t.GetData("Link Source Descriptor", true);
    object objectLink = t.GetData("ObjectLink", true);

    // Try replacing the text
    HTMLFormat = (object)HTMLFormat.ToString().Replace("|KeyWord_A|", "Value_A");
    t.SetData("HTML Format", HTMLFormat);
    sysString = (object)sysString.ToString().Replace("|KeyWord_A|", "Value_A");
    t.SetData("System.String", sysString);
    unicodeText = (object)unicodeText.ToString().Replace("|KeyWord_A|", "Value_A");
    t.SetData("UnicodeText", unicodeText);
    text = (object)text.ToString().Replace("|KeyWord_A|", "Value_A");
    t.SetData("Text", text);
            
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(t);
}
catch (exception ex)
{
    // Do exception handling
}
```

Inspecting all these objects I see that, even though they are apparently included in the DataObject, they are all null, except for HTML Format, System.String, UnicodeText and Text. Within these options the HTML Format data is the only one that appears to have some formatting data in there (I don't know where the included image is stored though). I am able to replace the keyword in that HTML Format succesfully, however if I set it back into the DataObject and then extract the HTML format again nothing has changed. The same goes for the other text items.

I also tried changing the text in the same way for all the text items. This however has the same results. If I then try to paste the clipboard contents into Word it freezes for a little while and then nothing happens.

How can I edit this DataObject? And will that actually translate into a properly formatted and layout-ed text including the image and hyperlinks, or is this approach a dead end?

Cheers!

Comment: *NOTHING* works with IE any more. Forget it. You can't edit data in the clipboard either, you have to replace it. Clipboard isn't needed to automate things anyway. If you want to control a web page, you need a tool based on WebDriver like Selenium or Playwright. RPA tools actually use one or the other to control the browser. When they allow you to record your steps, they actually use either tool's script recording.

Comment: Windows comes with a free version of Power Automate by now, which definitely doesn't use IE. This may or may *not* work well with SalesForce though - if elements have no ids, the tool will have to use XPath or CSS queries to identify the clicked elements and quite often they use the wrong queries. Check the [Playwright Getting Started](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro/) page to see how you can do the same without an RPA tool interfering. You can then modify the recorded scripts and use your own identifiers. Don't expect this to work as well as an API though